# Trigger not firing when inserting in table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am new to SQL and trying to create a trigger that adds data from different rows and tables into one table and one row when there is an insert into a table and I have gotten the trigger to have 0 errors but now it does not trigger when something is inserted into the table.

This is my current code:

```
CREATE TABLE Workshops (
    workshopID INT UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
    workshop_member INT UNIQUE,
    duration INT,
    costAmount DECIMAL(8 , 2 ),
    availablePlaces INT,
    workshopFrequency VARCHAR(100),
    cabinDescription VARCHAR(300),
    PRIMARY KEY (workshopID)
);

CREATE TABLE Booking (
    customerID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fName VARCHAR(25),
    lname VARCHAR(25),
    cusEmail VARCHAR(50),
    homeAddress VARCHAR(50),
    homeState VARCHAR(15),
    homePostcode INT,
    cusPhoneNumber INT,
    booking_workshop INT,
    workshopDate DATE,
    bookingTime TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (customerID)
);

CREATE TABLE GSO_Members (
    gsoMemberID INT UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
    gsoMemberName VARCHAR(50),
    contactName VARCHAR(50),
    dateStart DATE,
    dateEnd DATE,
    businessName VARCHAR(50),
    businessAddress VARCHAR(50),
    phoneNumber INT,
    gsoEmail VARCHAR(50),
    gspDescription VARCHAR(200),
    PRIMARY KEY (gsoMemberID)
);

CREATE TABLE CabinPurchase (
    cabinName VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE,
    occupancy INT,
    price INT,
    shippingCost INT,
    squaremeter INT,
    cabinDescription VARCHAR(200),
    dateDelivery DATE,
    datePurchase TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (cabinName)
);

CREATE TABLE MessagingSystem (
    messageID INT UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
    booking_customer INT UNIQUE,
    gsomember_to_send INT UNIQUE,
    workshop_booked INT UNIQUE,
    dateStamp TIMESTAMP,
    messageField VARCHAR(200),
    PRIMARY KEY (messageID)
);   


    -- assign foreign keys
ALTER TABLE Workshops 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (workshop_member)   
        REFERENCES GSO_Members (gsoMemberID);

ALTER TABLE Booking
ADD FOREIGN KEY (booking_workshop)
    REFERENCES workshops (workshopID);

ALTER TABLE MessagingSystem
ADD FOREIGN KEY (booking_customer)
    REFERENCES Booking (customerID),
ADD FOREIGN KEY (gsoMember_to_send)
    REFERENCES GSO_Members (gsoMemberID), 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (workshop_booked)
    REFERENCES Workshops (workshopID);


    -- Create Trigger
## when booking is made automatically insert message to message table 

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER auto_insert_messagingsystem
    AFTER INSERT ON booking FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO messagingSystem (booking_customer, gsoMember_to_send, workshop_booked, messagefield)
            SELECT new.customerID, gsoMemberID, workshopID, CONCAT(new.fname, ' ', new.lname, ' has booked ', new.booking_workshop, ' on ', new.workshopDate, '. Their contact details are ', new.cusPhoneNumber, ' and ', new.cusEmail, '.')
            FROM booking as a, gso_Members, workshops, booking as b;
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

I'm trying to have it so that the messaging system is automatically updated when a column in the booking table is inserted.

Comment: *FROM booking as a, gso_Members, workshops, booking as b* - this is incorrect. You must join tables correctly and filter them by the parameters of the row which' insertion fires the trigger.

Comment: Sorry what did you mean by "which insertion fires the trigger". could you clarify that please @Akina

Comment: Trigger fires for each separate row insertion (if a lot of rows is inserted then trigger is fired a lot of times, one time per each separate row).

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand. I guess I more don't understand "parameters of the row which' insertion fires the trigger." this is quite unclear to me as to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You insert the row. Each column in the row to be inserted have some definite value. I mean the array of these values.